# Sample DBRoulette app doesn't see files

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, dropbox-api

I’ve just downloaded the Dropbox SDK (v1.3.13), and I’m trying to get the example DBRoulette app working.

I've configured my app and my secret and the connection establishes fine. However the app doesn't see any .jpg photos that I'm putting in my App's folder (at Dropbox/Apps/MyAppName), I'm still getting this error:

> Put .jpg photos in your app's App folder to use DBRoulette!

In `-(void)restClient:loadedMetadata:` I `NSLog`’d `metadata.contents` and it resulted in `()`.

I'm running Xcode Version 6.3.2 (6D2105), iOS SDK 8.3.

I’m stumped!

Answer (score 0):

Everything was set up right, there was some kind of problem with the (official) Dropbox client on my Mac. Once I paused syncing then re-started syncing in the Mac client, the DBRoulette test app and my app proper started working.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure without seeing any code but my guess is you didn't set the 'root' path of your folder:

```
[self.restClient loadMetadata:@"/Apps/MyAppName"];
```

Comment: Thanks, that wasn't the problem. My root was set to `@"/"`, which was equivalent to `@"/Apps/MyAppName"` since I'd set the privileges to `kDBRootAppFolder`.